# MySQL is returning an alphabetically sorted column names when using Laravel's Schema::getColumnListing('table_name');

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table named `tags` with the following schema:

```
id
name
icon
type
```

[image]

If I use Laravel's `Schema::getColumnListing('tags')`, it returns an alphabetically sorted array of the column names:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "icon"
  1 => "id"
  2 => "name"
  3 => "type"
]
```

Am I right to expect that the returned array should be preserving the original column order? Like:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => "icon"
  3 => "type"
]
```

**Additional details, I'm using**:

- PHP 7.4.3
- mysql  Ver 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
- Laravel version is 5.8

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but maybe somebody else will find it helpful:

Instead of

```
Schema::getColumnListing('table_name')
```

I've used

```
collect(\DB::select('describe table_name'))->pluck('Field')->toArray();
```

It returned the same result while preserving the order of the rows as it is in the database.